# How to understand: "felony aggravated indecent assault" in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction, appositives

> The scene outside the court was quite a spectacle, but inside, Cosby was given some relatively good news. While his conviction on three counts of **felony aggravated indecent assault** had the potential to carry a 30-year sentence — with a maximum of 10 years each — Judge Steven O’Neill said that Cosby will be sentenced for just one count.

As I understand, '**felony**' and "**aggravated indecent assault**" are in apposition. Basically, they describe the same thing('felony', that is, "aggravated indecent assault"). But I'm not quite sure about it because usually we might add commas for appositives.

Have I gotten it wrongly?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/bill-cosby-sentencing-andrea-constand-family-deliver-emotional-statements-d-asks-judge-10-year-sentence-202325826.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't describe the *exact* same thing, that is the assault, and they don;t necessarily need to be collocated.

> **aggravated indecent assault**

describes the *crime*, and

> **felony**

describes the *seriousness* of the crime. As opposed to a *misdemeanor*.